# Hacking JavaScript Array Into JSON With Python

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am fetching a .js file from a remote site that contains data I want to process as JSON using the simplejson library on my Google App Engine site.  The .js file looks like this:

```
var txns = [
    { apples: '100', oranges: '20', type: 'SELL'}, 
    { apples: '200', oranges: '10', type: 'BUY'}]
```

I have no control over the format of this file.  What I did at first just to hack through it was to chop the `"var txns = "` bit off of the string and then do a series of `.replace(old, new, [count])` on the string until it looked like standard JSON:

```
cleanJSON = malformedJSON.replace("'", '"').replace('apples:', '"apples":').replace('oranges:', '"oranges":').replace('type:', '"type":').replace('{', '{"transaction":{').replace('}', '}}')
```

So that it now looks like:

```
[{ "transaction" : { "apples": "100", "oranges": "20", "type": "SELL"} }, 
 { "transaction" : { "apples": "200", "oranges": "10", "type": "BUY"} }]
```

How would you tackle this formatting issue?  Is there a known way (library, script) to format a JavaScript array into JSON notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too difficult to write your own little parsor for that using [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

```
import json
from pyparsing import *

data = """var txns = [
   { apples: '100', oranges: '20', type: 'SELL'}, 
   { apples: '200', oranges: '10', type: 'BUY'}]"""


def js_grammar():
    key = Word(alphas).setResultsName("key")
    value = QuotedString("'").setResultsName("value")
    pair = Group(key + Literal(":").suppress() + value)
    object_ = nestedExpr("{", "}", delimitedList(pair, ","))
    array = nestedExpr("[", "]", delimitedList(object_, ","))
    return array + StringEnd()

JS_GRAMMAR = js_grammar()

def parse(js):
    return JS_GRAMMAR.parseString(js[len("var txns = "):])[0]

def to_dict(object_):
    return dict((p.key, p.value) for p in object_)

result = [
    {"transaction": to_dict(object_)}
    for object_ in parse(data)]
print json.dumps(result)
```

This is going to print

```
[{"transaction": {"type": "SELL", "apples": "100", "oranges": "20"}},
 {"transaction": {"type": "BUY", "apples": "200", "oranges": "10"}}]
```

You can also add the assignment to the grammar itself. Given there are already off-the-shelf parsers for it, you should better use those.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to pyparsing...this will come in handy in the future.  Not sure which answer to accept yet.

Comment: One of the details I left out was that one of the fields in the array is a beast of characters that make yaml choke (:, ', ").  I'll need to suppress them and I think this solution will let me do that.

Comment: This is pretty nice, although it doesn't handle the true, false, and null keywords, or Unicode escapes (not sure if they will ever pop up).

Comment: It's not too difficult to extend the range of allowable values and add a little dictionary with builtins like those. I mostly wrote up that answer to advertise PyParsing:)

Answer (score 4):

I would use the yaml parser as its better at most things like this. It comes with GAE as well as it is used for the config files.  Json is a subset of yaml.

All you have to do is get rid of "var txns =" then yaml should do the rest.

```
import yaml

string = """[{ apples: '100', oranges: '20', type: 'SELL'}, 
             { apples: '200', oranges: '10', type: 'BUY'}]"""

list = yaml.load(string)

print list
```

This gives you.

```
[{'type': 'SELL', 'apples': '100', 'oranges': '20'},
 {'type': 'BUY', 'apples': '200', 'oranges': '10'}]
```

Once loaded you can always dump it back as a json.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of the yaml lib.  I am having some difficulty with one of the fields now ... it has some spurious characters that I have to suppress.  I might need to go with the pyparsing solution given that issue.

Comment: Greg, what issue are you having?

Comment: Basically I have some values with slashes, escapes, colons and apostrophes like 'oranges:with:1,ripe:\"yes\"' that just make it hard to sweep the text to do the original parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you **know** that's what it's always going to look like, you could do a regex to find unquoted space-delimited text that ends with a colon and surround it with quotes.

I'm always worried about unexpected input with a regex like that, though. How do you know the remote source won't change what you get?

Comment: I don't know if/when it changes ... it's a fragile solution to be sure and I'll have error handling to report when it changes.  But this is just for a hobby app. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate page containing a Javascript script that just loads the remote one and dumps it to JSON. Then Python can make requests to your intermediate page and get out nice JSON.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it to one hop because I'll be doing this with several files ... so multiply each extra hop by at least six for now.

Comment: You can bundle all your requests into one request to the intermediate page, so this only actually adds one hop total.